# What is the probability that I will be alive a month from now?

Tags: probability

The main reason for asking - I am considering doing something that has a certain element of risk - I estimate it at 0.1%

I could wait a month and do it with 0% risk.

Being a rational individual, I would like to know what is the math behind these two potential choices.

Assumptions:

- Current age: 30
- [Life expectancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_expectancy): 80
- Max lifespan: 120
- No escape longevity velocity, assume 120 and 80 are constant

**Knowing all of this - can you help me become a rational human being?**

Once I know how to calculate it, I'll plug some numbers into Google Sheets / Excel, tweak some other constraints *(here is only the probability of staying alive)* and will live happily ever after an optimized life.

---

One potential solution could be working backward.

- I'm 120 - what is the probability of living at least 1 month? 0%, keeping assumptions.
- I'm 119 and 11 months - ...
- I'm 119 and 10 months - ...

Intuitively, the change should not be linear, more something like this, natural factors involved:

[image]

***EDIT:*** I wrongly understood **median** and **mean**, sorry!

> Mathematically, life expectancy is the mean number of years of life remaining at a given age, assuming age-specific mortality rates remain at their most recently measured levels.

Therefore area 1 and area 2 are of equal size?

Feel free to make your own assumptions to simplify the case.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x)$ be the the function that you plotted, the probability of being alive at age $x$.  As you've already shown in your plot,

- $g(30)=1$ (you're alive at 30),
- $g(120)=0$ (you're dead at 120), and
- $g'(x)\le 0$ (once you die, you remain dead).

You also have

- $\int_{30}^{120} xg'(x)=-80$ (mean life expectancy at 30 is 80).

This is because if we let $f(x)=1-g(x)$ be the probability of being dead at age $x$, then $f'(x)$ is the probability density of dying at age $x$, so $\int_{30}^{120} xg'(x)=-\int_{30}^{120}xf'(x)=-80$.

You'll need additional assumptions to fully specify g, but these should cover those that you've provided so far.

Note: It's not necessarily true that $g(80)=1/2$, unless you also want to assume that the median life expectancy is 80.  It's also not necessarily true that the areas of regions 1 and 2 in your plot are the same.  The integral condition above is sufficient to ensure a mean life expectancy of 80.

Comment: OUCH! I've just realised the definition says "mean", not "median"... I'm not sure about assumption really, feel free to loose the requirements so it is easier to estimate.